# error with function pointer for callback

Tags: pointers

I have function pointer declaration as below:

```
 int Start(char* pName, void (*callback)(void *));
```

When I am passing function pointer like below:

```
Start("Name", &Service::callbackStatus(void*));
```

I am getting following error:

error: expected primary-expression before 'void'.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing function pointer to a function, just pass the function name.

```
Start("Name", &Service::callbackStatus);
```

Comment: Hey DAC84, Thanks for the reply. But my problem not solved. I am getting error as below:                                       error: no matching function for call to 'start::Start(const char [10], void (Service::*)())'

Answer (score 0):

Passing function pointer can be done the following way:

```
    int Start( char* pName, void (Service::* callback)(void *), Service& obj )
    {   
       (obj.*(callback))( pName );
       return 0;
    }

   ...    
   Service obj;
   Start( "Name", &Service::callbackStatus, obj );
```

But it is ugly way.

With C++ it is more elegant to pass pointer or reference of interface to the function:

```
class MyInterface
{
public:
   virtual void callbackStatus(void* a) = 0;
};

class Service : public MyInterface
{
public:   
   void callbackStatus(void* a) { std::cout << "hello\n";  }
};

int Start( char* pName, MyInterface& obj )
{   
   obj.callbackStatus( pName ); 
   return 0;
}

...
Service obj;
Start( "Name", obj );
```

Another way is pass pointer to static member function. It can be used similar way than normal non-member functions.